# Running php script and javascript onClick

Tags: php, onclick

I have the following line of code -

```
<a href="/wordpress/wp-content/trackclicks/clickcounter.php?var=<?php echo $var3; ?>" onclick="return popitup2();">Grab Coupon</a>
```

But suppose i want to redirect the current page to an external link and also run the php script and the javascript function.Is something like this possible -

```
<a href="{@extlink}" onclick="/wordpress/wp-content/trackclicks/clickcounter.php?var=<?php echo $var3; ?>; return popitup2(); ">Grab Coupon</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Ajax. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) are the docs for the JQuery variety.

Answer (score 0):

Either use javascript to call the clickcounter using ajax, or move the redirect into your click counter script, eg:

`clickcounter.php?var=<?php echo $var3; ?>&redirect=example.com`

Comment: so this redirect would be passed to the php script as a GET variable same as var?

Comment: yep, it would be available as $_GET['redirect'].